# How to test if list element exists?

Tags: r

#### Problem

I would like to test if an element of a list exists, here is an example

```
foo <- list(a=1)
exists('foo') 
TRUE   #foo does exist
exists('foo$a') 
FALSE  #suggests that foo$a does not exist
foo$a
[1] 1  #but it does exist
```

In this example, I know that `foo$a` exists, but the test returns `FALSE`.

I looked in `?exists` and have found that `with(foo, exists('a')` returns `TRUE`, but do not understand why `exists('foo$a')` returns `FALSE`.

#### Questions

- Why does `exists('foo$a')` return `FALSE`?
- Is use of `with(...)` the preferred  approach?

Comment: maybe `!is.null(foo$a)` (or `!is.null(foo[["a"]])` to be on the safe side) ? (or `exists("a",where=foo)`)

Comment: @BenBolker thanks - would make a good answer; why is the latter option preferred?

Comment: @David partial matching... try the above with `foo <- list(a1=1)`

Answer (score 181, accepted):

This is actually a bit trickier than you'd think. Since a list can actually (with some effort) contain NULL elements, it might not be enough to check `is.null(foo$a)`. A more stringent test might be to check that the name is actually defined in the list:

```
foo <- list(a=42, b=NULL)
foo

is.null(foo[["a"]]) # FALSE
is.null(foo[["b"]]) # TRUE, but the element "exists"...
is.null(foo[["c"]]) # TRUE

"a" %in% names(foo) # TRUE
"b" %in% names(foo) # TRUE
"c" %in% names(foo) # FALSE
```

...and `foo[["a"]]` is safer than `foo$a`, since the latter uses partial matching and thus might also match a longer name:

```
x <- list(abc=4)
x$a  # 4, since it partially matches abc
x[["a"]] # NULL, no match
```

[UPDATE] So, back to the question why `exists('foo$a')` doesn't work. The `exists` function only checks if a variable exists in an environment, not if parts of a object exist. The string `"foo$a"` is interpreted literary: Is there a variable called "foo$a"? ...and the answer is `FALSE`...

```
foo <- list(a=42, b=NULL) # variable "foo" with element "a"
"bar$a" <- 42   # A variable actually called "bar$a"...
ls() # will include "foo" and "bar$a" 
exists("foo$a") # FALSE 
exists("bar$a") # TRUE
```

Comment: it is still not clear - is there a reason why `exists('foo$a') == FALSE`?

Comment: This suggests there is generally no good solution for this in R! One might want more complex things (like testing if `$mylist[[12]]$out$mcerror` is defined) which would currently be complicated as hell.

Comment: Were you aware of the `where` argument to `exists` pointed out in @Jim's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25875605/199217)?

Comment: `"bar$a" <- 42` I really wish this was invalid syntax and exists("foo$a") worked in the naive sense.

Answer (score 55):

The best way to check for named elements is to use `exist()`, however the above answers are not using the function properly.  You need to use the `where` argument to check for the variable *within* the list.

```
foo <- list(a=42, b=NULL)

exists('a', where=foo) #TRUE
exists('b', where=foo) #TRUE
exists('c', where=foo) #FALSE
```

Comment: Using `exists()` on a list does work, but I believe that R internally coerces it to an environment before checking for an object of that name, which is inefficient and can result in errors if there are any unnamed elements.

For example if you run `exists('a', list(a=1, 2))`, it will give an error: `Error in list2env(list(a = 1, 2), NULL, <environment>) : attempt to use zero-length variable name`. The conversion happens here: https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/af7f52f70101960861e5d995d3a4bec010bc89e6/src/main/envir.c#L1943

Answer (score 6):

One solution that hasn't come up yet is using length, which successfully handles NULL. As far as I can tell, all values except NULL have a length greater than 0.

```
x <- list(4, -1, NULL, NA, Inf, -Inf, NaN, T, x = 0, y = "", z = c(1,2,3))
lapply(x, function(el) print(length(el)))
[1] 1
[1] 1
[1] 0
[1] 1
[1] 1
[1] 1
[1] 1
[1] 1
[1] 1
[1] 1
[1] 3
```

Thus we could make a simple function that works with both named and numbered indices:

```
element.exists <- function(var, element)
{
  tryCatch({
    if(length(var[[element]]) > -1)
      return(T)
  }, error = function(e) {
    return(F)
  })
}
```

If the element doesn't exist, it causes an out-of-bounds condition caught by the tryCatch block.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a performance comparison of the proposed methods in other answers.

```
> foo <- sapply(letters, function(x){runif(5)}, simplify = FALSE)
> microbenchmark::microbenchmark('k' %in% names(foo), 
                                 is.null(foo[['k']]), 
                                 exists('k', where = foo))
Unit: nanoseconds
                     expr  min   lq    mean median   uq   max neval cld
      "k" %in% names(foo)  467  933 1064.31    934  934 10730   100  a 
      is.null(foo[["k"]])    0    0  168.50      1  467  3266   100  a 
 exists("k", where = foo) 6532 6998 7940.78   7232 7465 56917   100   b
```

If you are planing to use the list as a fast dictionary accessed many times, then the `is.null` approach might be the only viable option. I assume it is O(1), while the `%in%` approach is O(n)?

Answer (score 4):

A slight modified version of @salient.salamander , if one wants to check on full path, this can be used.

```
Element_Exists_Check = function( full_index_path ){
  tryCatch({
    len_element = length(full_index_path)
    exists_indicator = ifelse(len_element > 0, T, F)
      return(exists_indicator)
  }, error = function(e) {
    return(F)
  })
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`rlang::has_name()` can do this too:

```
foo = list(a = 1, bb = NULL)
rlang::has_name(foo, "a")  # TRUE
rlang::has_name(foo, "b")  # FALSE. No partial matching
rlang::has_name(foo, "bb")  # TRUE. Handles NULL correctly
rlang::has_name(foo, "c")  # FALSE
```

As you can see, it inherently handles all the cases that @Tommy showed how to handle using base R and works for lists with unnamed items. I would still recommend `exists("bb", where = foo)` as proposed in another answer for readability, but `has_name` is an alternative if you have unnamed items.

Answer (score 0):

Use `purrr::has_element` to check against the *value* of a list element:

```
> x <- list(c(1, 2), c(3, 4))
> purrr::has_element(x, c(3, 4))
[1] TRUE
> purrr::has_element(x, c(3, 5))
[1] FALSE
```

Comment: Does it work if the element is nested / at any level of nesting? I checked the docs and it wasn't clear

Comment: @DavidLeBauer, no. In that case, I'd use `rapply` (something like `any(rapply(x, function(v) identical(v, c(3, 4)), how = 'unlist'))`)