# How to check if object (variable) is defined in R?

Tags: r

I'd like to check if some variable is defined in R - without getting an error. How can I do this?

My attempts (not successful):

```
> is.na(ooxx)
Error: object 'ooxx' not found
> is.finite(ooxx)
Error: object 'ooxx' not found
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 554, accepted):

You want `exists()`:

```
R> exists("somethingUnknown")
[1] FALSE
R> somethingUnknown <- 42
R> exists("somethingUnknown")
[1] TRUE
R>
```

Comment: @tim if you are inside a function, missing() is what you want.

Comment: Might get a bit trickier if checking for list elements: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7719741

Comment: what about for what the op wanted - using the variable name, not in quotes?

Comment: @tim `exists(quote(ooxx))`

Answer (score 132):

See `?exists`, for some definition of "...is defined". E.g.

```
> exists("foo")
[1] FALSE
> foo <- 1:10
> exists("foo")
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Well, if you will use ridiculously long object names ;-)

Comment: heh. Happens to me all the time when I am testing out examples before posting, Gavin or Josh have already answered it.

Answer (score 70):

if you are inside a function, missing() is what you want.

```
exchequer = function(x) {
    if(missing(x)){
        message("x is missing… :-(")
    }
}

exchequer()
x is missing… :-(
```

Comment: `missing` only works for function arguments, however. You can't do `foo <- function(x) {missing(x); missing(y)}` or you will get `foo(1)`
`> Error in missing(y) : 'missing' can only be used for arguments`.

Answer (score 64):

As others have pointed out, you're looking for `exists`. Keep in mind that using `exists` with names used by R's base packages would return true regardless of whether you defined the variable:

```
> exists("data")
[1] TRUE
```

To get around this (as pointed out by Bazz; see `?exists`), use the `inherits` argument:

```
> exists("data", inherits = FALSE)
[1] FALSE

foo <- TRUE
> exists("foo", inherits = FALSE)
[1] TRUE
```

Of course, if you wanted to search the name spaces of attached packages, this would also fall short:

```
> exists("data.table")
[1] FALSE
require(data.table)
> exists("data.table", inherits = FALSE)
[1] FALSE
> exists("data.table")
[1] TRUE
```

The only thing I can think of to get around this -- to search in attached packages but *not* in base packages -- is the following:

```
any(sapply(1:(which(search() == "tools:rstudio") - 1L),
           function(pp) exists(_object_name_, where = pp, inherits = FALSE)))
```

Compare replacing `_object_name_` with `"data.table"` (`TRUE`) vs. `"var"` (`FALSE`)

(of course, if you're not on RStudio, I think the first automatically attached environment is `"package:stats"`)

Comment: Playing around, using argument `inherits = FALSE` seems to isolate things in the global environment.  Does that sound right?

Comment: @Bazz you're correct; I've edited this into the answer.

Comment: This comment should be higher up, since I use variable name "data", just using exist gave me some trouble initially.

Answer (score 40):

If you don't want to use quotes, you can use `deparse(substitute())` trick which I found in the example section of `?substitute`:

```
is.defined <- function(sym) {
  sym <- deparse(substitute(sym))
  env <- parent.frame()
  exists(sym, env)
}

is.defined(a)
# FALSE
a <- 10
is.defined(a)
# TRUE
```

Comment: you can also `force` or evaluate it in the function like this: `is.defined <- function(sym) class(try(sym, TRUE))!='try-error'`

Comment: this answer may be a tad more complicated...but this is the ideal answer if you don't want to  contend with characters vs var-names

Comment: I have bumped into an issue that needs exactly your solution. When you wanted to use something that's not `NULL` for quosure (`enquo(x)` if x is not null), you need a good way to check if the expression passed in is not null. Your solution does exactly that. thanks

Answer (score 6):

If you don't mind using quotes, you can use:

> exists("x")

If you don't want to use quotes you can use:

> exists(deparse(substitute(x)))

Comment: This answer combines previous answers. Not sure if this is adding anything to the conversation so far.

Answer (score 2):

There may be situations in which you do not exactly know the name of the variable you are looking for, like when an array of results have been created by a queuing system. These can possibly be addressed with "ls" and its argument "pattern" that expects a regular expression.

The "exists" function could be reimplemented that way as

```
exists <-function(variablename) {
   #print(ls(env=globalenv()))
   return(1==length(ls(pattern=paste("^",variablename,"$",sep=""),env=globalenv())))
}
```

While preparing this answer, I was a bit surprised about the need for the need of the specification of the environment when invoking [ls()](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/ls.html) from within a function. So, thank you for that, stackoverflow! There is also an "all.names" attribute that I should have set to true but have omitted.