# R : Check if R object exists before creating it

Tags: r

I am trying to skip steps loading data from large files if this has already been done earlier. Since the data ends up in (for example) mydf, I thought I could do:

```
if( !exists(mydf) )
{
  #... steps to do loading here.
}
```

I got this from [How to check if object (variable) is defined in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9368900/how-to-check-if-object-variable-is-defined-in-r) and https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/exists.html

However R Studio simply complains with

```
'Error in exists(mydf) : object 'mydf' not found
```

Why does it complain instead of just returning 'true' or 'false'? Any tips appreciated.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You should use `exists("mydf")` instead `exists(mydf)`