# detect numeric values in a string

Tags: r

I have to create a function which will detect if there is any non numeric value present in input. For this I have written this code

```
test<-function(x){
  if(is.numeric(x)){
    return(T)
  }else{
    return(F)
  }
}
```

However when I test it with say

```
> test(a123)
Error in test(a123) : object 'a123' not found
```

But it works when i use quotes

```
> test("a123")
[1] FALSE
```

However I want it working in the first form. Any help on this will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Use ```exists()``` in conjuction with your function: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9368900/how-to-check-if-object-variable-is-defined-in-r

Comment: That are two different things: the string "a123" and the object with the name **a123**. BTW: Why do you write this function if it does the same as `as.numeric()` ?

Comment: Its just for validating if while entering values in code one has mistakenly included a symbol or an alphabet

Comment: I think what if you want to detect if there are *numeric* symbols in a *character*, you need a regular expression.

Comment: Yes. The objective is to detect if there are numeric symbols or characters mistakenly typed in while typing in numbers

Comment: Try `x <- deparse(substitute(x))` in your function ?

Answer (score 0):

`test(a123)` will not work. You have to store the user input in a object first and then pass it to your function.

Note that with your function  `test(123)` **also returns** `FALSE`! (even if you insert `deparse(substitute(x))` as suggested in the comments)

A shorter and correct way to perform your test is `grep("[^0-9]", x)` that returns 1 if the string `x` contains anything that is not a digit, 0 if not.

If you really want to have your function to work in what you refer to as the 1st form (but I think it is not a good idea as it can't receive any object and doesn't seem to have any use in an R script) :

```
test<-function(x){
  x<-deparse(substitute(x))
  grep("[^0-9]",x)
}

> test(123)
integer(0)
> test(a123)
[1] 1
```

Comment: The `grep` test should have `-`, `.` and `e` within the character class squeare-brackets to allow for decimals and scientific notation.