# Verify object existence inside a function in R

Tags: r, environment, scoping

I want to determine whether an object exists inside a function in R:

```
foo <- function() {
 y <- "hello" 
 if (exists(y, envir = sys.frame())) print(y)
}
foo()
```

> Error in exists(y, envir = sys.frame()) : invalid first argument

I thought adding the `envir = sys.frame()` would do the trick. Also tried `envir = environment()`

**Expected**

```
foo()
"hello"
```

Comment: Use `missing()` e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/15316362/2682264

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should have checked `?exists`:

```
Usage:

     exists(x, where = -1, envir = , frame, mode = "any",
            inherits = TRUE)

Arguments:

       x: a variable name (given as a character string).
```

Do `exists("y")`