# R - check if a variable exists

Tags: r

I thought I had figured this one out. I have a variable called:

```
count_1
```

It's just a vector with one element. As I go through my loops, sometimes it has a value, and at other times it doesn't. All I want to do is ask if it contains anything, and if not, merely loop back around. Right now my script fails because when count_1 is empty, I get this:

> missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
>   Execution halted

Here is my attempt so far:

```
if (exists("count_1"))
  { 
    #code#
  }
```

Comment: The error message means that your variable exists but contains a missing value, i.e., an `NA` value. Maybe you should use `if (!is.na(count_1))` or `if (is.finite(count_1))`. However, if you have many loops you are writing inefficient R code.

Comment: Maybe this requires a double check - `if (exists("count_1") & !is.na(count_1))`

Comment: @Roland `count_1 <- NA; if (exists("count_1")){ "yes" } else { "no" }` works... not sure how to reproduce above error.

Comment: @RonakShah Hmm I think that would fail if there'd be not `count_1`. Either `if (exists("count_1") && !is.na(count_1))` or two nested `if`s.

Comment: Actually the above code you had mentioned should work unless its `na`. If in loop just use `else { next } ` that should work I guess. In fact I tried something similar and it worked- `a <- 5 

rm(b)
if(a%%2 == 0 )
{
  b <- 1 
}

if(exists("b"))
{
  print('hi')
}else
{
  print('bye')
}
`

Comment: Related post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9368900

Comment: @zx8754 I believe their `#code#` contains some subsetting with a logical comparison or something similar.

Comment: @Roland so error is coming from `#code#` bit we know nothing about...

Comment: @zx8754 Yes, and they are trying to avoid it with the `if` condition.

Comment: @zx8754 There is also the possibility of an empty value, like `x <- integer(length=0)`. In that case `exists("x")` returns `TRUE` and `isTRUE(is.na(x))` yields `FALSE`, but there is still no value stored in `x`...

Comment: If I understand the discussion correctly: `if(length(count_1)==1)` should check for something with a value.

Comment: @nya I believe that this would be a good answer. Or maybe a more general comparison, like `if(length(count_1) > 0)` or so...

Comment: Never use `exists` for general code. This is a function to support infrastructure programming, it should simply never appear in normal analysis (or general user-level) code: if you write the code, *you should know* whether a variable exists. Asking the question inside the code is a sure sign that there’s a logic error in the code.

Answer (score 2):

Use `if(length(count_1) == 1) { next }` to check if there is a value in `count_1`.

However, this will only work if your code does something like this:

```
dat <- 1:5
count_1 <- which(dat > 10)
count_1
# integer(0)
length(count_1) == 1
# [1] FALSE
```

It will not work with another way of filling the variable, e.g.:

```
count_1 <- ifelse(any(dat > 10), which(dat > 10), NA)
count_1
# [1] NA
length(count_1) == 1
# [1] TRUE
```

Comment: Suggestion: Maybe it would be good to combine the two possibilities, empty and `NA` values, like this: `if (length(count_1) && !is.na(count_1))...`

Comment: @RHertel Absolutely. If we knew who the OP creates the variable, we could provide a bullet-proof solution.

Answer (score 2):

For a different reason, I need to check if a variable exists inside a function. I use this:

```
check=function(x) tryCatch(if(class(x) == 'logical') 1 else 1, error=function(e) 0) 
varX=1 
check(varX)
[1] 1
rm(varX)
check(varX)
[1] 0
f1= function(x) if(check(x)) cat('exists') else cat('not exists')
f1(varX)
not exists
```