# How to check if any variable is defined in argument (...) in R?

Tags: r, function, arguments, exists

If I have a function with argument (...) and want to check if a variable is defined in the argument. How can I do this? I have already looked at the solution provided at this link: [How to check if object (variable) is defined in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9368900/how-to-check-if-object-variable-is-defined-in-r). However, it does not solve my problem.

```
# Scenario 1
exists("a")
# [1] FALSE

# Scenario 2
a <- 10
exists("a")
# [1] TRUE

# Define a function for remaining scenarios
f = function(...){exists("a", inherits = F)}

# Scenario 3
f()
# [1] FALSE

# Scenario 4
a <- 10
f()
# [1] FALSE

# Scenario 5
a <- 10
f(a = 5)
# [1] FALSE
```

I want the answer to be `TRUE` in Scenario 5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this suffice?

```
# Define a function for remaining scenarios
f = function(...){"a" %in% names(list(...))}

# Scenario 3
f()
# [1] FALSE

# Scenario 4
a <- 10
f()
# [1] FALSE

# Scenario 5
f(a = 5)
# [1] FALSE

f(a = 5)
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Yes. This will help. Thank You!

Answer (score 3):

Generally you use `...` when you are passing parameters to other functions, not when you are using them in the function itself. It also makes a difference if you want to evaluate the parameter value or if you want to leave it unevaulated. If you need the latter, then you can do something like

```
f = function(...) {
  mc <- match.call(expand.dots = TRUE)
  "a" %in% names(mc)
}
```

This will return true for both

```
f(a = 4)
f(a = foo)
```

even when `foo` doesn't exist.

Comment: ok. Got it. It just that my intention is in two steps: 1) select function based on parameters defined in ```...```.  2) Pass the parameters to the function.