# How to check if an executable command exists in R

Tags: r

*Is there a way in R to check if a command exists in the operating system?*

I know that `file.exists(file)` can be used to check if a file exists. But what about a command on the system `PATH`?

(This is with Ubuntu 20.04, R 4.1).

Related:

[How to check if object (variable) is defined in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9368900)

[How can I check if a directory exists in a Bash shell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59838)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is a command in `PATH`, then it is actually a file somewhere in the search path.

An easy way is

```
system("which <command>")  # for unix
system("where <command>")  # for windows
```

If the command exists, then this should show the full path.  Otherwise nothing.

Comment: Are you sure this correct? On Windows, If I do `system("where dir")` I get "INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s)" but `system("which dir")` returns 127.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I will change the example.  But `where` would work for commands in the PATH though?

Comment: Note that [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/677212/11021886) recommends _avoiding_ using `which` to determine whether an executable is found on the system `PATH`. They recommend avoiding `which` as it doesn't consistently set exit codes across different operating systems, and as it can apparently do other "evil things". The `command` argument is recommended instead.

Answer (score 1):

### Short Answer

On linux:

```
is_bin_on_path = function(bin) {
  exit_code = suppressWarnings(system2("command", args = c("-v", bin), stdout = FALSE))
  return(exit_code == 0)
}
```

Example usage:

```
is_bin_on_path("ls")
# TRUE

is_bin_on_path("git")
# TRUE

is_bin_on_path("madeup")
# FALSE
```

### Tell me more

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/677212/11021886) recommends *avoiding* using `which` to determine whether an executable is found on the system `PATH`. They recommend avoiding `which` as it doesn't consistently set exit codes across different operating systems, and as it can apparently do other "evil things".

Instead, OP advocates using `command` as a safer alternative to `which`.

We can invoke `command` from `system2()` as:

```
system2("command", args = c("-v", executable))
```

where `executable` is a string representing the program you are checking for the existence of. eg. `"git"`, `"python"`, ...

If `executable` *is* on the system `PATH`, the location of the executable is printed. If we wish, we can suppress this by calling `system2()` with `stdout = FALSE`:

```
system2("command", args = c("-v", executable), stdout = FALSE)
```

If `executable` *isn't* on the system `PATH`, `system2()` will raise a warning:

```
system2("command", args = c("-v", executable), stdout = FALSE)
# Error in paste(c(env, shQuote(command), args), collapse = " ") :
#   object 'executable' not found
```

To suppress this warning we can wrap the command `system2()` command in a `suppressWarnings()`.

Finally, we should note that by default `system()` and `system2()` return the *exit code* of the invoked command, rather than the output of the command itself (as you might expect).

If the desired `executable` *does* exist on the system `PATHA`, our invocation of `system2("command")` will return with an exit code of `0`. Hence we can convert the exit code to a Boolean representing whether the executable exists on the system `PATH` as:

```
exit_code = suppressWarnings(system2("command", args = c("-v", bin)))
bin_on_path = exit_code == 0
```

Wrapping this up into something reusable we arrive at the function:

```
is_bin_on_path = function(bin) {
  exit_code = suppressWarnings(system2("command", args = c("-v", bin), stdout = FALSE))
  return(exit_code == 0)
}
```

#### Other notes

The more modern replacement of `system2()`, `processx()`, at least in my experience, seems unhappy calling `command`. I'm not sure why this is the case.