# How to check the existence of elements of list in r

Tags: r, matrix

How can I check if an element of list exists or not. This is a list of lists so for example I want to check whether the third element l1[[3]] exists or not. I have tried is.null(l1[["3"]]) 
but it returns false no matter whether it exists or not and if I use is.null(l1[[3]]) it will give the error of subscript out of bind in case it does not exists but not TRUE. 
How should I che

Comment: how about `length(l1)>2` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**tl;dr:**
If you want to check if element `n` exists, even if checking at end of a list or an empty list, use:

```
length(mylist) >= n   # TRUE indicates exists. FALSE indicates DNE
```

For nested lists, make sure to check the correct list.  eg:

```
 length(outerlist[[innerlist]]) >= n
```

---

NULL in lists in R has some differences from what one is used to in other languages.  For example, if we replace the element of a list by NULL, all subsequent elements are shifted over, and the list is left with a length of one less.

```
# SAMPLE DATA
mylist <- as.list(LETTERS[1:5])

    [[1]]
    [1] "A"

    [[2]]
    [1] "B"

    [[3]]
    [1] "C"

    [[4]]
    [1] "D"

    [[5]]
    [1] "E"
```

Testing for NULL in elements 3 & 6. Not quite the information we are looking for.

```
is.null(mylist[[3]])
# FALSE

is.null(mylist[[6]])
# Error in mylist[[6]] : subscript out of bounds
```

Instead we check the length of the list:

```
length(mylist) >= 3  # TRUE
length(mylist) >= 5  # TRUE
length(mylist) >= 6  # FALSE
```

Removing the 3rd element. Notice that the "empty slot" is **not** preserved. (ie, element 4, becomes element 3, etc..)

```
mylist[[3]] <- NULL

  [[1]]
  [1] "A"

  [[2]]
  [1] "B"

  [[3]]
  [1] "D"

  [[4]]
  [1] "E"


length(mylist) >= 3  # TRUE
length(mylist) >= 5  # FALSE
length(mylist) >= 6  # FALSE
```

#### An empty list will have length of 0

```
emptyList <- list()
length(emptyList)  # 0

nestedList <- list( letters=list("A", "B", "C"), empty=list(), words=list("Hello", "World"))

length(nestedList)
  # [1] 3
lapply(nestedList, length)
  # $letters
  # [1] 3
  #
  # $empty
  # [1] 0
  #
  # $words
  # [1] 2
```

---

Note that you **can** incoporate NULL into a list. Which is when testing for NULL is applicable.  For example:

```
myListWithNull <- list("A", "B", NULL, "D")

is.null(myListWithNull[[3]])
  # TRUE

length(myListWithNull) >= 3
  # TRUE
```

Comment: this is useful but I think you might spell out the implications for the OP (who might be an R newbie) a bit more.  In particular it doesn't really answer the question (how do I tell if element 3 of a list exists?)

Comment: It also might be the last element of the list which I do not know whether it exists or not. How can I check its existence?

Comment: @hora, part of the issue might be in how one defines "exists". How specifically do you mean? What would be an example of it existing, what would be an example of non-existence?

Comment: For example in your sample, how do you check whether the sixth element exists or not?

Comment: by using `length()`.  If the length is `>= 6` then the 6th element exists else it does not.  In my example, note the difference when checking for the 5th element before and after removing one element.

Comment: @hora, please see revisions in answer above

Comment: yes. Finally I got it. Sorry I feel like some how stupid now :)))

Answer (score 1):

As I posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50538644/8785542), rather than checking the length of the whole list, it's possible to check the length of the element itself to check for NULL values. As far as I can tell, all values except NULL have a length greater than 0.

```
x <- list(4, -1, NULL, NA, Inf, -Inf, NaN, T, x = 0, y = "", z = c(1,2,3))
lapply(x, function(el) print(length(el)))
[1] 1
[1] 1
[1] 0
[1] 1
[1] 1
[1] 1
[1] 1
[1] 1
[1] 1
[1] 1
[1] 3
```

Thus we could make a simple function that works with both named and numbered indices:

```
element.exists <- function(var, element)
{
  tryCatch({
    if(length(var[[element]]) > -1)
      return(T)
  }, error = function(e) {
    return(F)
  })
}
```

If the element doesn't exist, it causes an out-of-bounds condition caught by the tryCatch block.

Answer (score 1):

As evaluation of statements in if stops as soon as a condition is false, you can use the following to reliably check if an element is empty:

```
if(length(l1)<n || is.null(l1[[n]]){ # TRUE only if not NULL
}
```

Alternatively you can use named lists

```
is.null(l1[["a"]])
```

behaves independently from the length of the list.