# Input ID not initialized when defined within conditionalPanel

Tags: r, shiny

In the sidebar of my Shiny app, I am looking to offer filtering by the values of a certain variable only when a checkbox activating that filter has been checked before. I am trying to implement this as follows:

```
checkboxInput("filterByDistrict", "Activate filtering by district", FALSE),

  conditionalPanel(
    condition = "input.filterByDistrict == true",
    checkboxGroupInput(
      "districts", 
      label = "Choose a district:", 
      choices = choicesList,
      selected = choicesList
    )
  )
```

What I found is that the `districts` input variable never gets initiated. I am using it on the server side, where the check for its existence always fails:

```
...
if(exists(input$districts)) {
...
```

What am I missing/doing wrong?

Comment: I assume you meant to write:

    `...
    if(exists("input$districts")) {
    ...`

since `exists()` requires a string input but regardless it wouldn't work for list input as described below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input is defined, but `exists` doesn't work with list elements, try :

```
"districts" %in% names(input)
# or
!is.null(input$districts)
```

Comment: For more info, you can refer to [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7719741/how-to-test-if-list-element-exists)

Comment: This put me on the right track, thanks! Indeed nothing was wrong in the bits I described, the erroneous behavior I observed was caused elsewhere.