# How to extract second value from a list of lists and give NA to lists with no second value?

Tags: r, lapply

I'd like to extract the first and second values from a list of lists. I was able to extract the first value with no issue. However, it gives me an error when I was trying to extract the second value because not all lists from the `suggestion` column has more than one value. How can I extract the second value from the `suggestion` column in `mydf_1` and generate NA to those with no second value?

Below are the codes I wrote to get to the first suggestion, but when I do

`` mydf_1$second_suggestion <- lapply(mydf_1$suggestion, `[[`, 2) ``

it gives this error: 
`Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : subscript out of bounds`

Thanks.

```
# create a data frame contains words
mydf <- data.frame("words"=c("banna", "pocorn and drnk", "trael", "rabbitt", 
                               "emptey", "ebay", "templete", "interne", "bing", 
                               "methog", "tullius"), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

# add a custom word to the dictionary$
library(hunspell)
mydict_hunspell <- dictionary(lang="en_US", affix=NULL, add_words="bing", 
                              cache=TRUE)

# use hunspell to identify misspelled words and create a row number column 
#   for later uses
mydf$words_checking <- hunspell(mydf$word, dict=mydict_hunspell)
mydf$row_num <- rownames(mydf)

# unlist the words_checking column and get suggestions for those misspelled 
#   words in another data frame
library(tidyr)
mydf_1 <- unnest(mydf, words_checking)
mydf_1$suggestion <- hunspell_suggest(mydf_1$words_checking)

# extract first suggestion from suggestion column
mydf_1$first_suggestion <- lapply(mydf_1$suggestion, `[[`, 1)
```

Comment: sorry, my bad, let me edit it

Comment: Try `lapply(mydf_1$suggestion, "[", 2)`.

Comment: that doesn't work

Comment: Are you sure? Working fine for me. Perhaps replace " with `.

Comment: this is the error is generated: ```Error: unexpected '[' in "mydf_1$second_suggestion <- lapply(mydf_1$suggestion, ["```

Comment: there you go, the " ". Thank you!!

Comment: @jay.sf I can mark it as an answer if you post it

Comment: It's fine for me, there are already a bunch of similar answers, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169456/the-difference-between-bracket-and-double-bracket-for-accessing-the-el

Comment: @jay.sf - yeah, it even returns `NA` when selecting out-of-range values - `lapply(list(1:2, 1, 3:4), \`[\`, 1:2)` for instance.

Comment: very interesting read, thank you for sending it over.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the length of each list first before trying to extract the element of interest.   Also, I recommend using sapply so that you have a character vector returned, as opposed to another list.

For the first suggestion:

```
index <- 1
sapply(mydf_1$suggestion, function(x) {if(length(x) < index) {NA} else {x[[index]]}})
```

And for the second suggestion and so on:

```
index <- 2
sapply(mydf_1$suggestion, function(x) {if(length(x) < index) {NA} else {x[[index]]}})
```

This could be wrapped into a larger function with a bit more code if you need to automate...

In theory, you could test with `is.null`(see [How to test if list element exists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7719741/how-to-test-if-list-element-exists) ), but I still got the same error trying that approach.